# RegEx for extracting specific variables and values

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am using Google Vision API to extract the text (handwritten plus computer-written) from images of application forms. The response is a long string like the following.

The string:

```
"A. Bank Challan
Bank Branch
ca
ABC muitce
Deposit ID VOSSÁETM-0055
Deposit Date 16 al 19
ate
B. Personal Information: Use CAPITAL letters and leave spaces between words.
Name: MUHAMMAD HANIE
Father's Name: MUHAMMAD Y AQOOB
Computerized NIC No. 44 603-5 284 355-3
D D M m rrrr
Gender: Male Age: (in years) 22 Date of Birth ( 4-08-1999
Domicile (District): Mirpuskhas Contact No. 0333-7078758
(Please do not mention converted No.)
Postal Address: Raheel Book Depo Naukot Taluka jhuddo Disstri mes.
Sindh.
Are You Government Servant: Yes
(If yes, please attach NOC)
No
✓
Religion: Muslim
✓
Non-Muslimo
C. Academic Information:
B
Intermediate/HSSC ENG Mirpuskhas Bise Match
Seience BISEmirpuskhas Match
2016
2014
Matric/SSC"
```

The whole response isn't useful for me, however I need to parse the response to get specific fields like Name, Father's Name, NIC No., Gender, Age, DoB, Domicile, and Contact No.

I am defining patterns for each of these fields using regular expression library (re) in Python. For example:

```
import re
name ='Name: \w+\s\w+'
fatherName = 'Father\'s Name: \w+\s\w+\s\w+'
age ='Age: \D+\d+'

print(re.search(name,string).group())
print(re.search(fatherName, string).group())
print(re.search(age,string).group())
```

Output:

```
"Name: MUHAMMAD HANIE
Father's Name: MUHAMMAD Y AQOOB
Age: (in years) 22"
```

However these are not robust patterns, and I don't know whether this approach is good or not. I also cannot extract the fields that are on same line, like Gender and Age.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try capturing then in groups `\nName: (.*)\nFather's Name: (.*)\nComputerized NIC No\. (.*)\n.*\nGender: (\w+) Age: \(in years\) (\d+) Date of Birth \( *([\d-]+)\nDomicile \(District\): (.*?) Contact No\. ([\d-]+)` See https://regex101.com/r/vRVoXQ/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. Your pattern can help. :) There are thousands of such strings. I will need to define patterns for each of these fields separately, so that I can capture them into appropriate variables, and populate the columns accordingly in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be robust, however it is possible to design an expression to extract the three parameters that you wish. [This tool](https://regex101.com/r/fhCQky/1/) can help you to do so. Maybe, you might want to have an expression with several boundaries:

```
(?=[A-Z])((Name:[A-Z-a-z\s]+\n|\s)|(Father\x27s\sName[A-Z-a-z\s\.]+\n|\s)|(Age:\s\(in\syears\)\s[0-9]+))
```

It might be good to focus on the text you wish to extract.

#### Variances

- Age: This variable seems to be simple to extract
- Name and Father's Name: You might want to check how the values may look like in these two variables so that to add it to a char list. I've just assumed that, maybe this would be a list of char: `[A-Z-a-z\s\.]`. However, you can change/simplify it, as you wish.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualizes your expressions:

[image]

#### Python Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = """
A. Bank Challan
Bank Branch
ca
ABC muitce
Deposit ID VOSSÁETM-0055
Deposit Date 16 al 19
ate
B. Personal Information: Use CAPITAL letters and leave spaces between words.
Name: MUHAMMAD HANIE
Father's Name: MUHAMMAD Y AQOOB
Computerized NIC No. 44 603-5 284 355-3
D D M m rrrr
Gender: Male Age: (in years) 22 Date of Birth ( 4-08-1999
Domicile (District): Mirpuskhas Contact No. 0333-7078758
(Please do not mention converted No.)
Postal Address: Raheel Book Depo Naukot Taluka jhuddo Disstri mes.
Sindh.
Are You Government Servant: Yes
(If yes, please attach NOC)
No
✓
Religion: Muslim
✓
Non-Muslimo
C. Academic Information:
B
Intermediate/HSSC ENG Mirpuskhas Bise Match
Seience BISEmirpuskhas Match
2016
2014
Matric/SSC"""
expression = r'(?=[A-Z])((Name:[A-Z-a-z\s]+\n|\s)|(Father\x27s\sName[A-Z-a-z\s\.]+\n|\s)|(Age:\s\(in\syears\)\s[0-9]+))'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(2) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "Name: MUHAMMAD HANIE" is a match
```

Comment: Thanks @Emma for such a detailed answer and the links. Not only three fields but Name, Father's Name, NIC No., Gender, Age, DoB, Domicile, and Contact No. Actually there are thousands of such strings. I will need to define patterns for each of these fields separately, so that I can capture them into appropriate variables, and populate the columns accordingly in the database.

Comment: dob = 'Date of Birth \( *([\d-]+)'
print(re.search(dob,data).group())
Output: Date of Birth ( 4-08-1999.

Any idea how to remove '(' or any unnecessary words, while defining pattern? I just need 4-08-1999.

Comment: thank you! :) I am not used to this platform, so will take some time to make it useful for me.